# How to replace /n with <li> tags in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of the following form

`Hello \n\tHow are you?\n\t`

I want to replace it with

`<li>Hello</li> <li>How are you?</li>`

I am able to replace `/n to <br>` using
`message.replaceAll("\\n\\t","<br>");`

But I am not sure how to replace with `<li>***</li>` tags. I tried this `message.replace("/[^\r\n]+/g", "<li>$&</li>");` but it does not work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you seem to have drawn this conclusion:

- Hey, I can replace newlines with `<br />` tags using `.replace`. I generalize that turning string inputs into HTML structures therefore must always be done with replace...
- so how do I use replace to make `<li>`-structured HTML instead?

This is a brainfart - you've made jumps that you shouldn't be making. Specifically, `.replace` is **not** a good idea, generally, for converting unstructured text into structured HTML. It's really just the 'newlines to br tags' transformation that can feasibly be done with `.replace` and very little else, and only because that is an oversimplification that usually fails, except for that specific transformation.

Specifically, you tried `message.replace("/[^\r\n]+/g", "<li>$&</li>")` which obviously doesn't work - `replace` **does not apply regular expressions at all** - perhaps you wanted `replaceAll`. You *CAN* probably attempt to use replaceall to do this job but it wouldn't be a good idea. It's like the question: "Can you butter your toast using a clawhammer?" - Yes, you can. That is no proof that it's a good idea. Just use a buttering knife if you want to do it right, and 'but it works with this clawhammer' doesn't change that fact.

So let's break it down.

What you actually want to do is take your input which *is* unstructured, but represents structured data, into its actual structure *first*, and only then convert the structure you have into `<li>`-tag based HTML. In other words, it's a *two step model*:

1. Convert your input string into the structure you believe it holds.
2. Convert that structure back into the output you want.

With each step having its own proper solution depending on what kind of structure it holds, what the input is formatted as, and what output you want.

In this specific case it seems easy enough: The structure is 'the input consists of a number of lines, separated by a newline character', and the desired output is 'each line, HTML-escaped, as a list item in a `<ul>` HTML element'.

So let's do that:

First, we recover the actual structured data. Given that your structure is 'a bunch of lines', `List<String>` sounds like a data type that properly represents this. So, we need to convert the input into a `List<String>`. Let's get to it:

```
List<String> myData = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\R"));
```

Then, you solve the completely separate problem of converting your now properly structured data into a desired output, which is now also quite easy:

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
html.append("<ul>");
for (String line : myData) {
  html.append("<li>").append(htmlEscape(line)).append("</li>");
}
html.append("</ul>");
return html.toString();
```

Where `htmlEscape` is for example powered by guava's HtmlEscaper - usually if you're doing web stuff you have some framework or other on the classpath with this functionality. If you must have it on your own, it's probably as simple as:

```
// Ampersand must remain first character.
private static final String HTML_PROTECTED = "&<>\"'";
private static final String[] HTML_REPLACEMENTS = {"amp", "lt", "gr", "quot", "apos"};

public String htmlEscape(String s) {
  for (int i = 0; i < HTML_PROTECTED.length(); i++) {
    s = s.replace("" + HTML_PROTECTED.charAt(i), "&" + HTML_REPLACEMENTS[i] + ";");
  }
  return s;
}
```

But, those frameworks no doubt have faster implementations of this idea.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other ways of approaching this:

```
       String input = "Hello \n\tHow are you?\n\t";
        List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            listItems.add(String.format("<li>%s</li>", s.nextLine().trim()));
        }

        System.out.println(listItems);
        
        listItems = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input)).lines().map(line -> String.format("<li>%s</li>", line.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(listItems);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by tokenizing your string like this example below:

```
    String myString = "Hello \\n\\tHow are you?\\n\\t";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myString, "\\n\\t");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.format("<li>%s</li>\n", st.nextToken().trim());
    }
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is considered legacy and should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the for loop in java. You can write something like that:

```
for (char ch : "test".toCharArray()) {
    //do something with character ch
}
```